# Switching two times over a specified interval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timer, setinterval

I have been building an Interval Timer and I have got a bit stuck trying to switch between the `activeTime` and `restTime` and loop for the specified `interval` count.

Basically I would like the timer to run for 3 Intervals where the active time is 5 seconds and the rest time is 2 seconds.

I have managed to get the timer counting down but I'm struggling to figure out how to switch between the two times for that set Interval amount.

Here is what I have so far:

**InvervalTimer.vue**

```
<template lang="">
  <div class="interval-timer">
    <div class="countdown">
      {{ time }}
    </div>
    <div class="countdown-controls">
      <button v-if="!isRunning" @click="startTimer()">start</button>
      <button v-if="isRunning" @click="stopTimer()">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="interval-details">
      <div class="active-period">Active: {{ timer.active.time }}</div>
      <div class="rest-period">Rest: {{ timer.rest.time }}</div>
      <div class="intervals">Intervals: {{ timer.intervals }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'IntervalTimer',

  data: () => ({
    count: 0,
    isRunning: false,
    interval: 0
  }),
  props: ['timer'], // See Timer Object JSON bellow
  computed: {
    active() {
      return this.timer.active
    },
    rest() {
      return this.timer.rest
    },
    // Rest
    restTime() {
      const timeLeft = this.rest.totalSeconds - this.count

      if (this.rest.totalSeconds === this.count) {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
        this.count = 0
      } else {
        const mins = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60)
        const secs = timeLeft % 60
        if (mins > 10) {
          const mins = parseInt('0' + mins)
        }
        return mins + ':' + secs
      }
    },
    // Active
    activeTime() {
      const timeLeft = this.active.totalSeconds - this.count

      if (this.active.totalSeconds === this.count) {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
        this.count = 0
      } else {
        const mins = Math.floor(timeLeft / 60)
        const secs = timeLeft % 60
        if (mins > 10) {
          const mins = parseInt('0' + mins)
        }
        return mins + ':' + secs
      }
    },

    time() {
      const activeTime = this.activeTime
      const restTime = this.restTime
      if (activeTime <= 0) {
        this.stopTimer()
        return restTime
      } else {
        return activeTime
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    counting() {
      return this.count++
    },
    startTimer() {
      if (!this.interval) {
        this.isRunning = true
        this.interval = setInterval(this.timeIt, 1000)
      } else {
        this.isRunning = false
        clearInterval(this.interval)
        this.interval = 0
      }
    },
    timeIt() {
      this.count++
    },
    stopTimer() {
      this.isRunning = false
      clearInterval(this.interval)
      this.interval = 0
      this.count = 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Timer Object passed to Props**

```
{
  "active": {
    "minutes": 0,
    "seconds": "5",
    "time": "0:5",
    "totalSeconds": 5
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "seconds": 1549034224,
    "nanoseconds": 540000000
  },
  "intervals": "3",
  "rest": {
    "minutes": 0,
    "seconds": "2",
    "time": "0:2",
    "totalSeconds": 2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you haven't modeled your problem very clearly. You ought to have a structure that keeps track of remaining intervals, active seconds-this-interval, and rest seconds-this-interval. Each second, you decrement active if it's > 0, else decrement rest if it's > 0, else if intervals > 0, decrement intervals and reset active and rest.